# Facebook Staging Image vs Upload Image difference

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, staging

I'm learning Facebook Graph API about posting object to the graph and came across two methods

startForUploadPhoto:completionHandler:

and

startForUploadStagingResourceWithImage:completionHandler:

But I can't still see the difference between them, then I came across this paragraph

We can assign our objects images that are hosted in a server, by using the image's url, or we can assign them images local to the user's device, for example photos from the user's photo gallery. You can use Facebook's image staging service to host an image local to the user's device and then use this image to assign it to an Open Graph object (or action). The following code shows you how to modify your code in order to do this:

But still I don't seem to see the difference between when to use the 1st or 2nd method. Please explain. Thanks